# What should I do if the session value is getting null between .vb pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I added `session("username")="John"` in page A. And the same session I am trying to get in different page in the same project the session value is getting null.

Comment: Use a 2nd webpage to get to new page instead of trying to use the original webpage.

Comment: But my requirement is from Web page A I am opening a popup data grid of web page B, after closing web page B my all sessions are clearing off

Comment: Is page A still opened or closed?  If there is any authentication occurring when you open your first session.  You need to keep at least one session open so you do not need to authenticate again when going between pages.

Comment: page A still opened & authentication  party you're trying tell me. i have no idea about that